# GnuWin32 Convert tiff to pdf

Tags: pdf, tiff

I want to convert tiff files to pdf using [GnuWin32 tiff2pdf](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tiff.htm) utility.

I have tried following syntax:

```
tiff2pdf file.tiff
```

but it says program encountered an problem.

Will be thankfull if any one can help.

/R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify an output file. This is the issue, I guess.

Please try the following:

```
tiff2pdf −o output.pdf input.tiff
```